# How can I return a content-type style mime type from the FileInfo package?

Tags: php, mime-types

```
$finfo = new Finfo();
echo $finfo->file('image.jpg' );
```

As this stands, it outputs "JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01"

How can I modify this behaviour to output "image/jpeg"?

I would have liked to use the 'file' command but I'm not permitted to run system commands.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify what info you need - `FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE` in your case:

```
$finfo = new Finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
echo $finfo->file('image.jpg');
```

Outputs:

```
image/jpeg
```

Comment: Thanks Aleks, and also new Finfo(); echo $finfo->file('image.jpg', FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);